# How to loop sprite when it touches the border (android game development)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

please help. I am new to android game development and java. I want my deer to loop or start from 0,0 again when it touches the border of the screen but i have no idea how to code it.

package com.cmanres.bunnyjourney;

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;



public class Spriteleft {
       private static final int BMP_COLUMNS = 3;
   private static final int BMP_ROWS = 2;
   private int x = 0; 
   private int y=0;
       private int xSpeed = 3;
       private Levelunogame gameView;
       private Bitmap deer1;
   private int width;
   private int height;
   private int currentFrame=0;

 public Spriteleft(Levelunogame gameView, Bitmap deer1) {
         this.gameView=gameView;
         this.deer1=deer1;
         this.width = deer1.getWidth() / BMP_COLUMNS;
         this.height = deer1.getHeight() / BMP_ROWS;
   }

   private void update() {
         if (x > gameView.getWidth() - width - xSpeed) {
                xSpeed = -3;
         }
         if (x + xSpeed< 0) {
                xSpeed = 3;
         }
         x = x + xSpeed;
         currentFrame = ++currentFrame % BMP_COLUMNS;
   }


   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         update();
         int srcX = currentFrame * width;
         int srcY = 1 * height;
         Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
         Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);
         canvas.drawBitmap(deer1, src , dst, null);
       }
 }
```

that is my code that i followed on a android mobile game tutorial. can anyone show me how to do it? or give any links for a tutorial? I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: rewrite the `update` code appropriately. Note that letting an object jump into view doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sprite is positioned at x, y with sprite_width, sprite_height

// Check if your sprite position is outside the screen bounds

```
if( x < 0 || x > gameView.getWidth() - sprite_width 
 || y < 0 || y > gameView.getHeight() - sprite_height ) {
    // Set x, y to 0,0
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
```